# Symfony 2.4.1 ClassNotFoundException

Tags: symfony

Hello I dont know how to fix this bug , I searched in google but I got no solution for this bug, i am just trying to follow this tutorial http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/validators-and-forms.html, any help will be appreciated

```
ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Enquiry" from namespace      
"Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity" in       
C:\wamp\www\symblog.dev\src\Blogger\BlogBundle\Controller\PageController.php line 22.
Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?
```

this is the file code:

```
<?php
// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Controller/PageController.php
namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Controller;

// Import new namespaces

use Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Enquiry;
use Blogger\BlogBundle\Form\EnquiryType;

class PageController extends Controller
{

public function indexAction()
{
return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Page:index.html.twig');
}

public function aboutAction()
{
    return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Page:about.html.twig');
}

public function contactAction()
{
    $enquiry = new Enquiry();
    $form = $this->createForm(new EnquiryType(), $enquiry);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // Perform some action, such as sending an email

        // Redirect - This is important to prevent users re-posting
        // the form if they refresh the page
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('BloggerBlogBundle_contact'));
    }
    }

return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Page:contact.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}   
}
```

Comment: Can you copy also first 20 lines of Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Enquiry.php ?

Answer (score 0):

*Make sure:*

<kbd>1</kbd> the name of your file is `Enquiry.php`

<kbd>2</kbd> it is in the folder `Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity`

<kbd>3</kbd> it is called `class Enquiry`

<kbd>4</kbd> the namespace is `namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity;`

---

*Note:* The reason is that this is very often due to a typo in either the name of the file, the name of the class, the use statement or the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it starting PageController.php like this:

```
<?php
    // src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Controller/PageController.php

    namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Enquiry;
    use Blogger\BlogBundle\Form\EnquiryType;
```

If you find a better solution, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your namespaces are all right, check if your PHP file really has `.php` extension.